# What's is wrong with this WHERE Clause in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, syntax, syntax-error

Please, I need help!

Don't matter where I put this clause: WHERE romaneios_detalhes.id_romaneio = '.$idr.'
it's always returns a syntax error... I tried with and without the "table_name.", after and before all setences of my statment, with and without commas... nothing works and I am sure the solution is pretty simple...

What is the right place or right way to write this?

```
$sql3   =   'SELECT
         produtos_linhas.linha AS `COUNT(linha)`,
         produtos_tipos.tipo AS `COUNT(tipo)`, 
         COUNT(romaneios_detalhes.quantidade) AS `COUNT(quantidade)` 
         FROM romaneios_detalhes
         WHERE romaneios_detalhes.id_romaneio = '.$idr.'
         INNER JOIN produtos ON romaneios_detalhes.codigo = produtos.codigo
         INNER JOIN produtos_linhas ON produtos.id_linha = produtos_linhas.id
         INNER JOIN produtos_tipos ON produtos.id_tipo = produtos_tipos.id
         GROUP BY produtos_linhas.linha, produtos_tipos.tipo ';

echo '<p>'.$sql3.'</p>';
/* OUTPUT OF THIS ECHO:
SELECT produtos_linhas.linha AS `COUNT(linha)`, produtos_tipos.tipo AS `COUNT(tipo)`, COUNT(romaneios_detalhes.quantidade) AS `COUNT(quantidade)` FROM romaneios_detalhes WHERE romaneios_detalhes.id_romaneio = 3 INNER JOIN produtos ON romaneios_detalhes.codigo = produtos.codigo INNER JOIN produtos_linhas ON produtos.id_linha = produtos_linhas.id INNER JOIN produtos_tipos ON produtos.id_tipo = produtos_tipos.id GROUP BY produtos_linhas.linha, produtos_tipos.tipo
*/

$qry3   =   mysql_query($sql3) or die ($qry3_err.mysql_error());
```

Comment: Try the statement on the mysql command line first. The order should be "select ... from ... join ... group by ... where ...".

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that your WHERE clause is in the wrong place; it must be **after** your JOIN clauses.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the INNER JOINS MUST go before the where clause!

You need to move the where clause at the end, before the group by.

Answer (score 1):

Icarus and Brian are right, move WHERE below the JOINs.

Just a note, I hope $idr is not coming unprotected from a ?parameter or something, or you will be vulnerable for SQL injection.

Comment: Icarus, help me... I dont understand about sql injection... $idr comes from $_GET['id_romaneio']. How to protect this kind of parameter from sql injection?

Comment: @acchile I am not a php developer but the way I've seen other php developers protect against sql injection is that they escape the parameters by calling the mysql_escape_string func http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: @Icarus, or [mysqli with prepared statements/placeholders](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), cleaner (in my opinion) and closer to other languages.